# How to set rpc timeout in thrift python client?

Tags: python, rpc, thrift

I'm writing python client using thrift, but I can't find any available option to set rpc time out.

My client code goes below:

```
socket = TSocket.TSocket(address, port)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(socket)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
server = Client.Client(protocol)
transport.open()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `socket.setTimeout()` method.

```
from thrift.transport.THttpClient import THttpClient
socket = THttpClient(server_url)
socket.setTimeout(SERVICE_TIMEOUT_IN_mS)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(socket)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
```

Comment: Just for reference, the settimeout does indeed affect send, recv and connect operations, with no way of separating these timeouts.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: also note that TSocket.setTimeout takes milliseconds, but socket.settimeout takes a float in seconds!