# Setting connection and read timeout for sockets in python thrift client

Tags: python-2.7, thrift

I am executing the following code for establishing a thrift server using the official thrift library of python.

```
    `transport = TSocket.TSocket(self.__host, self.__port)`
    `transport.setTimeout(2000)`
```

Would this set a sum total of connect timeout and read timeout to 2 seconds or is it simple the connect timeout. If so, how do I set the read timeout and vice versa.

Comment: same question with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034768/how-to-set-rpc-timeout-in-thrift-python-client)

Comment: @shangliuyan I want to ask if you can set read and connect timeout separately. Also, the setTimeout method takes which timeout into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The settimeout affects separately each operation: for example send, recv and connect operations.
It looks like you cannot set the read timeout differently from the connect timeout.
Also the timeout is for each operation so if you do a connect and then a read, you will have 2 + 2 seconds max possible time.
See this which is the method that the thrift TSocket uses: 
[socket.settimeout(...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)